# Making ICommand and ViewModel

Tags: c#, uwp

I have programming for C# and UWP apps. I am using a video for learning ICommand but in that video, We create a class like this. Can you explain what is this?
Specially What is meaning of `return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);`? because I didn't see something like this in C# coding. I didn't see this method of typing.

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand (Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public void  RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Please read a good C# tutorial. It's also unclear what part of that line confuses you

Comment: Check out this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

```
return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
```

Return `true` is either or both statements evaluate to `true`.

So if the `_canExecute` function delegate is `null` or the invocation of the function results to `true` then return `true` else return `false`.

It is a basic logical OR operation.

Why it is written this way is because if the left side of the statement is true it immediately returns `true` without evaluating the right side. It will only look at the right side if the left side evaluates to `false`.

Which is safe because that would mean that `_canEcevute` is not `null` and thus `_canEcevute(parameter)` is safe to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first have a look at the constructor signature:

```
DelegateCommand (Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute = null)
```

As you can see, the second parameter `canExecute` is optional and has a default value of `null`. The semantics of this class is as follows: By passing a second parameter (that does not equal null), you state that `Action<object> execute` is executable if and only if `Func<object,bool> canExecute` applied to an object returns `true`. If you do not pass a second parameter or you pass `null` as second parameter, you state that `Action<object> execute` can always be executed. Please also note that the value of `bool CanExecute(object parameter)` is not checked by `void Execute(object parameter)`, so you have to do that yourself in order to avoid those exceptions that are thrown because of wrong parameters.

Now to your question: The line

```
return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
```

is only a shorter form of writing

```
var tmp = ((_canExecute == null) || (_canExecute(parameter)));
return tmp;
```